# Mutate according to conditions on multiple rows in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, transition, dplyr

How can I evaluate a condition on multiple rows in `dplyr`?
I have a dataset which I want to mutate according to conditions happening (transitions) on multiple time periods.

Following the example below if one passes by a bad status it has to be treated as bad overall. I tried `mutate_if`but it does not work, or probably I am not able to understand the syntax

```
df <-
  data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
             Date= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
             Money = c(500,400,500,100,100,100,200,300,300), 
             Status = c("Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good","Good","Good", "Bad","Good","Good"))
```

Could you provide me a solution to reach the below results? I would prefer staying inside the boundaries of `dplyr` if possible, although I know some good treatment could be performed with `datatable`

```
result <- 
  data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                     Date= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                     Money = c(500,400,500,100,100,100,200,300,300),
                     Status = c("Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good","Good","Good", "Bad","Good","Good"),
                     Status_overall = c("Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Good","Good","Good", "Bad","Bad","Bad"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `'Bad'` if `any` `Status` is `'Bad'` in a `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Status_overall = if(any(Status == 'Bad')) 'Bad' else 'Good')
  #Without if/else
  #mutate(Status_overall = c('Good', 'Bad')[any(Status == 'Bad') + 1])

#    ID  Date Money Status Status_overall
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         
#1     1     1   500 Good   Bad           
#2     1     2   400 Bad    Bad           
#3     1     3   500 Good   Bad           
#4     2     1   100 Good   Good          
#5     2     2   100 Good   Good          
#6     2     3   100 Good   Good          
#7     3     1   200 Bad    Bad           
#8     3     2   300 Good   Bad           
#9     3     3   300 Good   Bad
```

This can be written in base R and `data.table` as :

```
df$Status_overall <- with(df, ifelse(ave(Status == 'Bad', ID, FUN = any), 'Bad', 'Good'))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Status_overall := if(any(Status == 'Bad')) 'Bad' else 'Good', ID]
```

Comment: Do all and any work in this way? Because I tried all but I got an error

Comment: What error do you get? It works for me for the example data you shared. If you have `NA` values in your real data use `na.rm = TRUE` in `any`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(Status_overall = case_when('Bad' %in% Status ~ 'Bad', TRUE ~ 'Good'))
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID  Date Money Status Status_overall
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         
1     1     1   500 Good   Bad           
2     1     2   400 Bad    Bad           
3     1     3   500 Good   Bad           
4     2     1   100 Good   Good          
5     2     2   100 Good   Good          
6     2     3   100 Good   Good          
7     3     1   200 Bad    Bad           
8     3     2   300 Good   Bad           
9     3     3   300 Good   Bad
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `if` with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(Status_overall = if('Bad' %in% Status) 'Bad' else 'Good')
```